# Printing an array in a single dialog box (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

This is the current code I have. It works but it would output the numbers in multiple dialog boxes. I don't have any idea how I should print them in a single dialog box, separated by lines.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SecondClass
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {

        int stringLength;
        char num[];


        String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Input numbers", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); //input
        stringLength = value.length(); //getting string length and converting it to int
        num = value.toCharArray(); //assigning each character to array num[]


            for (int i = 0; i <= stringLength; i++) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You entered " + num[i] , "Value", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); //output box
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this snippet:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= stringLength; i++) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You entered " +
                 num[i] , "Value", 
                 JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); //output box
 }
```

To

```
String out="";

 for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
                out+= "You entered " + num[i] ;
 }
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, out, "Value\n", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: (int i = 0; i <= stringLength; i++) should be (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Gives an error: actual and formal argument lists differ in length.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)  {
           out+= "" + num[i] + "\n";
   }
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, out, "Value", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

Redone it. The problem is it also prints the null value...

Comment: @FriencyLoriagaFernandez great

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need extra `loop`, when you can directly display the output:

```
public class SecondClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input numbers",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); // input
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered " + value, "Value",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // output box
    }
}
```

**Loop version:**

```
public class SecondClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char num[];
        String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input numbers",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); // input
        num = value.toCharArray(); // assigning each character to array num[]
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            builder.append(num[i]);

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered " + builder, "Value",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // output box
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a StringBuffer to put all your answer in a long string (seperated by line breaks of course) and then show it on a dialog when you are done ?